# Running Cron scheduled jobs - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron

Not a question so much as an answer. After installing Civi 4.7.6 under WP, I tried running all scheduled jobs using: easyCron, Cron (through CPanel) with wp-cli, cron.php, and from commandline  curl, php...wp-cli, php...cron.php.  Finally I was successful running all jobs using URL 'https://mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cron.php?user=adminuser&password=mypwd&key=sitekeyfromcivicrmsettings
I had to move civicrm.settings.php to wp-content/plugins/civicrm - the install had placed it under wp-content/plugins/uploads/civicrm.   Some errors I got when trying to run as an actual cron job (putting it into crontab) referred to 'not finding default/civicrm.settings..' which sounds to me like a Drupal-oriented message, since that's where Drupal civicrm.settings.php go but not Wordpress.
HTH someone else.

Answer (score 1):

I had verified by running php -v (after shelling in) that (cli) was supposedly enabled but I could not submit a cron job using wp-cli.  I tried using curl, but got "Protocol http or https not supported or disabled in libcurl".  I didn't fare well with easyCron - I felt uneasy supplying my pswd there; but after seeing jobs tagged with 200 ('succeeded') in logs, my installation didn't reflect that.  One important bit of information - this site isn't live yet, so I am pointing to it via my Hosts file. But I have to verify that stuff works BEFORE go-live.
So, from where I stand, using the URL method seemed to be the one workable method.
(also, I could run it locally and debug it!)